# What is the difference between assigning permissions via Admin console versus the web portal?

Tags: tfs, permissions

We are using TFS 2013.

1. We can assign users to the project by going to the web portal dashboard of the project, and click on Manage and add members to team.
2. Other way is to click on the gear icon on top right and manage users from there.
3. Another way is to open the TFS admin console and assign permissions from there.

I would like to know the differences between these 3 approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the TFS documentation? Coz its pretty clear in there.

Comment: Please point to reference link

Comment: I am sure if you use a search engine you will immediately discover what you want.